# nginx is still on port 80 - bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx

I edited this file:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

to `listen 4444;` - https://dpaste.de/nrUy9/

but still is on port 80. What can I do? Port 80 is used by apache.

My error:

```
root@user /etc/nginx/sites-enabled # service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
nginx.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the IPv6 bind block (something along the lines of ::1:80

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain where exactly?

Comment: cd /etc/nginx && grep -R listen * will show you where

Comment: Thanks, now my sites work good on `domain.com:33333` (port). How to change it to work without `:33333`

Comment: Can you rephrase the question please?

Comment: I changed default port in nginx (from 80 to 33333). Now all my websites running on nginx work good only If I run in browser `domain.com:33333`. If I run `domain.com` did not work. How to fix it?

Comment: but your port 80 is already bind()-ed by Apache?

Comment: yes,is bind by apache

Comment: so request that go to port 80 are handled from Apache and requests that go to port 33333 are handled by nginx. If you want nginx to use port 80 you must stop Apache. Not two programs can listen on the same port.